# Featherlight close acts differently than manual close

Tags: featherlight.js

See this fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/JNsu6/460/

The loop simulates my situation where the content of the lightbox is being closed via `$.featherlight.current().close()` then re-opened. The only difference is in my situation it is happening due to a focus issue where the button clicked to open it is retaining focus and pressing the enter button on the keyboard causes the lightbox to open again, displaying the duplicate content. I mention this just to note that it isn't the speed of the loop that is causing the issue.

For some reason, the `$.featherlight.current().close()` does not clear out the content, however, clicking the "x" in the top right and manually closing it, then re-opening does. Looking at the code, they both call the same close function in the code.

Can you help to explain this and let me know how I can clear the content? Is there a setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the effects, `close()` isn't immediate, so there's something wrong going on.

If you add `$.fx.off = true;` at the beginning of your fiddle, everything works.

Solutions I can see would be to:

- try using `afterClose` callback
- or use different DOM elements (say using `clone()`)
- or reuse the same featherlight instead of closing + opening

Maybe it's possible to tweak the FL code itself to avoid the interaction and issue a PR, I don't know what it would entail tbh. Feel free to open an issue for this, it's kind of a bug.

Finally, there's [a fork that uses CSS effects](https://github.com/timint/featherlight) that might work better for you. Sadly, nobody has had time to make clean commits out of it to merge into FL.

HTH

Comment: Perfect, I may look deeper at the FL code at some point if I have time but it is working fine for me. I don't suspect it is a common issue as it can be avoided altogether with a different (and likely better) implementation. It is worth noting that similar to the `$.fx.off = true;`, I can just use `$(".featherlight").finish();` before calling again if I need update it. Since it was already open the close animation is not needed. Thank you for the plugin and fast support!